HyperX Cloud Stinger Microphone Not Detected in Ubuntu, Works on Windows (Dual Boot, Audio Jack)
I'm having an issue with my HyperX Cloud Stinger headset microphone not being detected on Ubuntu 24.04. The headphones work perfectly, but the microphone isn't recognized or listed in the sound settings or pavucontrol. I'm using the headset via the audio jack, and I am a dual boot user, where the microphone works without any problems on Windows.
Here are the troubleshooting steps I have tried so far:
Verified sound settings and pavucontrol for input sources.

(only the device microphone is listed here)
Checked alsamixer to ensure the microphone is not muted, adjusted capture settings.

Ran lspci and aplay -l to check for audio devices. I couldn't find my hardware device

Force reloaded ALSA and updated apt packages.
Followed various forum suggestions, but none worked.
Since the microphone functions fine on Windows and I'm using the audio jack, I believe this could be an Ubuntu-specific driver or configuration issue.
